# Moving a drawing

Tags: lua

This is an example of a drawing for the program I use

```
DrawCircle(mousePos.x, mousePos.y, mousePos.z, 650, ARGB(255, 255, 0, 0))
```

pretty simple x,y,z location radius of the circle and color, in this example it will draw a circle around my mouse and if my mouse moves the circle moves with it as is should, however what I would like to do is know how to draw a circle at lets say stationary position x,y,z and make the circle move from said position to new position a,b,c at x speed. sure I can just disable the draw at the starting point and redraw it at the destination point but I want the circle to visually move from point a to point b at speed x and I'm not sure what math I would need to be able to do this, furthermore if I was to draw a line how could I rotate that line in place so it looked like lets say helicopter blades spinning? Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about LUA per se, but the solution to your problem is based around vector mathematics.  LUA may have provide transformation functions to move a point in 3D space... not sure.  As for the rotor blade question, if you are plotting the rotor blade in a 2D plane, you simply need a bit of trigonometry.  There are *lots* of examples on the web, e.g.: [trig example](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/programming-natural-simulations/programming-angular-movement/a/trigonometry)